Can Simmons' Submarine-Destroyer Problem be solved using geometry without ODEs?
George Simmons, in his classic book on differential equations, poses this problem:

A destroyer is hunting a submarine in a dense fog. The fog lifts for a moment, discloses the submarine on the surface 3 miles away, and immediately descends. The speed of the destroyer is twice that of the submarine, and it is known that the latter will at once dive and depart at full speed in a straight course of unknown direction. What path should the destroyer follow to be certain of passing directly over the submarine? Hint: Establish a polar coordinate system with the origin at the point where the submarine was sighted.

This problem is solved here and elsewhere using differential equations.  I believe I've solved it using only simple geometry.  My solution is a simple constant heading, very different than the solutions referenced, which use exponentials.
Is my solution correct? Why does it seem so different than the cited solutions? Can you help me prove my conjectures at the end?

Proposed Solution
Call the point where the submarine surfaced $O$. The destroyer should head directly towards $O$.  Assume this takes $k$ seconds.  The destroyer should continue in a straight line for an additional $k$ seconds, and then spiral around $O$ with a constant heading of $120$° away from $O$ (that is, a heading $30$° outside a circle around $O$) and will catch the sub on its first loop.
Proof
Let the speed of the submarine be $1$ and the speed of the destroyer $\alpha$ with $\alpha > 1$.  (The problem specifies $\alpha = 2$, but we will give a general method.)
The destroyer should head directly towards $O$.  Assume this takes $k$ seconds.  The destroyer should continue in the same direction for an additional $\frac{k}{1 - \frac 1 \alpha} - k$ seconds (thus traveling in a straight line for $\frac{k}{1 - \frac 1 \alpha}$ seconds) and then spiral around $O$ at a constant heading of $\phi = \arccos (- 1  / \alpha)$ away from $O$.
Let the submarine's distance from $O$ be $S(t)$, and the destroyer's $B(t)$.  Let $t_0$ be $\frac{k}{1 - \frac 1 \alpha}$ seconds after the sighting.  Then $$S(t_0) = \frac{k}{1 - \frac 1 \alpha} \\
B(t_0) = \alpha \cdot \left[ \frac{k}{1 - \frac 1 \alpha} - k \right] = S(t_0).$$  Furthermore, since the component of the destroyer's velocity in the radial direction is $- \alpha \cos \phi$, we have for all $t$ $$S(t) = S(t_0) + t \\ 
B(t) = B(t_0) - t \alpha \cos \phi = S(t)$$ as required.
By symmetry, I conjecture this is the optimal solution (optimal worst case, best case, and mean case), and that it forms an Archimedean spiral around $O$.
Update: Although I'd like help to prove the conjectures, or to explain the discrepancy between this and the ODE solutions above, even a simple "Your proof looks correct" or "Here's your error" would be very appreciated.

First of all, I don't understand what your $\phi$ actually means. Second, where have you specified the angle at which the submarine is moving relative to $O$? Your "as required" leaves me wondering ... why are the two ever at the same point for some $t$?

@TedShifrin If the destroyer is heading towards $O$, then $\phi = 0$.  If it is heading directly away from it, then $\phi = \pi$.  And if it heads in a perfect circle around it, then of course $\phi = \pm \pi/2$.   As for the submarine: It moves in a straight line with a constant but unknown angle $\theta$ relative to $O$.  That's specified by the problem statement.

@TedShifrin Since the destroyer makes a complete loop, at some point it will be at any given angle $\theta$ relative to $O$.  We just need to show that at that point, it's distance $B$ from $O$ is the same as the sub's distance $S$. We show this in fact true for all $t > t_0$, and so as soon as the destroyer reaches the sub's angle, they will coincide.  Please let me know if that clarifies.

OK, I see. Now how do we get that following your constant heading results in $S(t)$ as you specified? Somewhere there needs to be some calculus.

@TedShifrin Since the sub moves in a straight line, its velocity $1$ is entirely in the radial direction, hence $S(t) = S(t_0) + t$.  Since the destroyer moves at angle $\phi$ with speed $\alpha$, only $\alpha \cdot - \cos \phi$ is in the radial direction, hence $B(t) = B(t_0) + t \cdot \alpha \cdot - \cos \phi$.

Sorry, I meant $B$. I think an integral is required here. The direction is merely instantaneous.

@TedShifrin I haven't been able to unpack your argument re the integral.  The direction is indeed instantaneous, but the destroyer can change heading (not position!) instantaneously.  Would you consider elaborating your ideas into an answer (not necessarily a complete solution, just, say, enough to show something concrete).

The two types of solutions are identical, merely differently described. The path with polar coordinates $(r(t), \theta(t)) = (t, \sqrt3 \ln t)$ is exactly the path with a speed of $2$ and a constant heading of $120^\circ$ away from the origin: these are two different descriptions of the same logarithmic spiral.
To see this, let's switch to rectangular coordinates: $x(t) = t \cos(\sqrt3 \ln t)$ and $y(t) = t \sin(\sqrt3 \ln t)$. Then we can write their derivatives as
\begin{align}
   x'(t) &= (t \cos(\sqrt3 \ln t))' = \cos (\sqrt{3}\ln t) - \sqrt3 \sin(\sqrt3 \ln t) \\
   &= 2 \cos\left(\frac\pi3 + \sqrt3 \ln t\right),\\
   y'(t) &= (t \sin(\sqrt3 \ln t))' = \sin(\sqrt3 \ln t) + \sqrt3 \cos(\sqrt3 \ln t) \\
   &= 2 \sin \left(\frac\pi3 + \sqrt3 \ln t\right).
\end{align}
The speed is $2$ (based on the constant in front), which is what we wanted the destroyer to be doing. The direction is $\frac\pi3 + \sqrt3 \ln t$ or $\frac\pi3 + \theta(t)$. This is $60^\circ$ counterclockwise from the direction pointing straight away from the origin, which is what is being described in this question as a constant heading of $120^\circ$.
If you look at a specific answer like this one, then it follows a slightly different strategy to get onto this spiral: instead of going full speed ahead toward the submarine, it waits in place until it ends up on the path, and then follows it. This is a cosmetic change.
My intuition is that the optimal way to get onto the spiral is to head in the direction of the submarine's original location for $2$ miles (at which point the destroyer would meet the submarine, if the submarine decided to head directly toward the destroyer from the start), then start spiraling.

Very clear and helpful, thank you

"the proposed answer... uses complicated facts about polar geometry, which is unnecessary when we can solve the problem with simple ODEs" I've studied the linked answers, and they all seem to need the same exact polar geometric facts, namely that velocity has two components, one in the radial direction (which changes radius) and the other perpendicular (which changes $\theta$).  Or the equivalent in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ in determining path length.
I don't see how the other solutions use ODEs to avoid requiring this knowledge.   Can you clarify?

Upon reflection, I retract my statement; I thought your solution was doing more complicated things than it was in fact doing.
